# Handle Large DataLists in java

Tags: java, memory

I am working on a rating system which loads millions of tariff plans into the memory before going for rating,
the tariff plans list keep growing on a daily basis (sometimes > 20k records daily) and from last few weeks we are facing memory issues.
Loading a certain number of tariffs based on date criteria is also not feasible due to some business rules.

Is there a way to implement some kind of caching mechanism (divide the tariffs in batches and loading/unloading them as needed)? 
or to memory-map the tariff list?

We are using hibernate for database fetching.

Comment: When dealing with such numbers, you have to define a strategy very precisely tied to the problem, so we can't answer as we don't know what really needs to be in memory and the read/write operations. It's almost sure that using something like hibernate is a bad idea when you have to precisely manage loading and unloading. You may use java nio and direct disk mapping to memory, RandomAccessFile and Channels, but one more time it's hard to say a priori.

Answer (score 0):

loading and unloading millions of objects in java is always too heavy for memory, and is not the best thing to do in java. I also agree with dystroy that hibernate is not the best option here.

Infact, you need to start thinking in lines of moving the logic outside java, either in stored procedure or some native implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your problem is really an Algorithm problem and not a memory problem. Try structuring your data in a tree and load only data branches that you're crossing at a specific moment. When you finish you unload data of that branch and load the new one. This is how I see it but there may be a better algorithm. This is going certainly to be slower.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with such numbers, you have to define a strategy very precisely tied to the problem, so we can't answer as we don't know what really needs to be in memory and the read/write operations.

It's almost sure that using something like hibernate is a bad idea when you have to precisely manage loading and unloading.

You should :

- define the rating requirements (probably already done)
- check it can't be done in a usual way (there are numerous rating systems and known strategies)
- require (for example on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) an idea for your rating
- only then can we say if you should use RandomAccessFile and nio Channels, or jdbc and smart loading, or just a few queries

Be careful that rating is generally a hard theorical problem. See [this interesting article](http://evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html) for example.

As a more direct element of answer, I'd say I do very fast read and write on many simultaneously open 4 Go files using RandomAccessFile and [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html).